# Short story pre-1990 involving intelligent rats

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I just spotted [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41337/the-rat-race-young-adult-1970s-really-smart-mice-and-rats?rq=1) which reminded me of a short story with some similarities in English that I read in the late 1980s (it was reprinted in a primary school textbook as part of a comprehension exercise so I have no idea about the cover, I'm afraid). It definitely *isn't* the rats of NIMH.

It was written in the form of a series of letters written by a scientist documenting the rapid increase in intelligence of an individual rat or small group of rats on an island. I think he was experimenting on it/them in some way, but I can't be sure about that. The tone of his letters grows increasingly alarmed. The final letter, written in suspiciously broken English (possibly also described as in terrible handwriting), then says (paraphrasing) "all the rats have suddenly died out and I am about to kill myself, nothing to see here, probably best if you do not visit this island again".

Does this ring any bells with anyone?

Comment: "The Lysenko Maze" has intelligent rats, but it's not epistolary. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122613/scientists-accidentally-breed-super-intelligent-mice

Comment: I'm wondering if it is the short story 'Barney' by Will Stanton? It's from the 50s so could have made it's way into a collection of short stories at a later date and reads like a chronological journal and the scientist logging it finds Barney to be smarter and smarter than he thought. The difference here is that the story only revolves around 1 rat on an island.

Comment: Also how odd - I've seen that name before, but "was the protagonist of The Dark Is Rising named after 1950s author Will Stanton" is *definitely a separate question :)

Comment: Came here to say "NIMH", shot down immediately. :) Unrelated, but it also reminded me of a [favorite (webcomic) story](http://www.agirlandherfed.com/1.95.html) with a koala learned to talk after [government-sponsored vivisectionists](http://grrlpowercomic.com/archives/1034) messed with his brain. Warning - the koala is far less benevolent or politically correct than the rats of NIMH.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm wondering if it is the short story [Barney by Will Stanton](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58880)? It's from the 50s so could have made its way into a collection of short stories at a later date and reads like a chronological journal and the scientist logging it finds Barney to be smarter and smarter than he thought. The last entry is indeed the narrator apologising for his bad handwriting:

> I sprayned my wrist is why this is written so bad.

and the narrator says:

> Do not look for my body as I will caste myself into the see.

The only difference here is that the story only revolves around one rat on an island.

Comment: I added a couple of extracts from the story to support your answer. Please feel free to roll back my change if you don't like it.

Comment: It does look like Barney has been used as an [English-class exercise in critical thinking/reading](https://criticalthinkingactivity.blogspot.com/2007/05/image.html), which jives with OP saying it was reprinted in a textbook.

Comment: I know you're supposed to wait before accepting but the quotes clinched it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Could it be [Flowers for Algernon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowers_for_Algernon)?

The story is told through a series of journal entries written by the story's protagonist, Charlie Gordon, a man with a low IQ of 68 who works a menial job as a janitor in Donnegan's Plastic Box Company. He is selected to undergo an experimental surgical technique to increase his intelligence. The technique had already been successfully tested on Algernon, a laboratory mouse. The surgery on Charlie is also a success, and his IQ triples. He realizes his co-workers at the factory, who he thought were his friends, only liked him around so they could tease him. His new intelligence scares his co-workers, and they start a petition to have him fired, but when Charlie learns about the petition, he quits.

But:

> As Charlie's intelligence peaks, Algernon's suddenly declines—he loses his increased intelligence and mental age, and dies afterward, buried in the back yard of Charlie's home. Charlie realizes his intelligence increase is also temporary. He starts to experiment to find the cause of the flaw in the experiment, which he calls the "Algernon–Gordon Effect". When he finishes his experiments, his intelligence regresses to its original state. Charlie is aware of, and pained by, what is happening to him as he loses his knowledge and his ability to read and write. He tries to earn back his old job as a janitor, and tries to revert to normal, but he cannot stand the pity from his co-workers, landlady, and Ms. Kinnian. Charlie states he plans to "go away" from New York and move to a new place. His last wish is for someone to put flowers on Algernon's grave.

Comment: Given that the OP has accepted an answer to the contrary, no, it can not.

Comment: Still worth leaving the answer here for people who search for "intelligent rats" though :)

Comment: Yep - it isn't Flowers for Algernon but I agree that's worth leaving up for future visitors (and maybe partly because it's one of my all-time favourites). :)

Comment: Please avoid summarizing the entire story.  That will ruin it for anyone who has not read it yet!  At least hide the story summary, so that the user has to mouse over it to see it.

Comment: @Panzercrisis you're always welcome to edit a post if you think it gives away too much.

Comment: @WillCrawford As far as I can see, the **only** point that matches is "intelligent rats", the stories are completely different otherwise; and the OP's question had more detail than just "intelligent rats". I don't think this is the place to collect all the intelligent-rodent stories in the world. (*Mrs. Frisby and the Rats of NIMH*? "The Star Mouse"? "The Lysenko Maze"? "Giant Killer"? There are *lots* of them.

Comment: [Related meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11662/31394) (cc @JohnRennie)

Comment: And Algernon wasn't even a rat, so technically only the word "intelligent" matches.

Comment: @user14111  I disagree, there are a lot more similarities than just intelligent rats. OP says the story was written as a series of letters with bad english at the end, both  Barney and FfA are written as a series of journal entries where the grammar and spelling deteriorate near the end.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, a mouse is not a rat, but they're very similar. Similar enough for someone trying to remember a story to mix up.

Comment: @mgillesp Good point. The actual story "Flowers for Algernon" was very different from "Barney", but not so very different from the OP's description. I stand corrected.

Comment: It could be Flowers for Algernon if the story were quite different.

Answer (score -1):

The story is by Will Stanton and was published first in *"Fantasy and Science Fiction"* in 1951 and last in *"Crime Fiction"* by Ernst Klett Sprachen GmbH, a German educational publisher with an emphasis on the teaching of languages, as well a few times in between those two dates.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! It would appear this has already been answered and accepted with that appears to be the same story (though you fail to include the name of the story, only the author). Your answer could also be improved by [edit]ing in any details which match the OPs description. Lastly, you say you are author's daughter but we have no way to verify this nor does this help the OP see if the story matches so I have edited it out.

Comment: But man... if you could provide some additional insights on the story by virtue of your relation, and be able to source them a bit, that would be a nice added answer.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots if they can also prove the relation. Simply claiming it is not enough.

Comment: @Edlothiad: 
That is true, although any information that is also backed up by additional sources works either way.