# Researcher trains a mouse to be more intelligent, it saves his life, and his final report is a handwritten note: "Send mor cheese"

Tags: story-identification

I am not sure this was in SF&F, but it's about a researcher who is training a mouse to be more intelligent.  He makes great gains, as documented in his weekly typed reports; he is able to communicate with the mouse.  In his penultimate report, he tells how the mouse saved his life.  The narrator was in a well and heard the mouse frantically squeaking above him.  When he came up, he saw the rope was frayed (he had not seen this before) and he would have been stuck in the well if the rope broke.

The next, and final, report is handwritten, scrawled, and says 'send mor cheese'.

Does anyone recognize this story?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall approximately when you read this?  Do you mean the *Fantasy & Science Fiction* magazine?

Comment: Possibly "Barney" as explained in this answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179662/28516 although some remembered details don't match. IIRC the request is for female rats.

Comment: Checked the Luminist archive here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1swtkq_hZMXsv4y7jhWvO2l8T-MWt0TzP/view, it's definitely Barney and a duplicate.

Answer (score 41):

The last message isn't a match, but the details about the frayed rope match "[Barney](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58880)" (*Fantasy & Science Fiction*, February 1951) very well:

> In order to facilitate my descent into the well I knotted a length of three-quarter inch rope at one foot intervals to make a rude ladder. I reached the bottom easily enough, but after only a few minutes of groping for the key, my flashlight gave out and I returned to the surface. A few feet from the top **I heard excited squeaks from Barney, and upon obtaining ground level I observed that the rope was almost completely severed. Apparently it had chafed against the edge of the masonry and the little fellow perceiving my plight had been doing his utmost to warn me.**

The last message is written in poor English and includes the excuse of a sprained wrist, presumably to explain poor handwriting.  It asks for the island to be left alone except for the delivery of young female rats:

> You mite bring a couple of young ratts an leeve them as a living memorial to Barney. Females—no males. I sprayned my wrist is why this is written so bad.

Comment: If accepted, duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179662/28516

Comment: Was the mouse trying to warn him? Or was it excited because it had almost finished chewing through the rope?

Comment: @Adamant it was trying to kill the researcher.

Comment: story at https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v002n01_1951-02_AK/page/n85/mode/2up

Comment: @Adamant human researchers don't need to write notes asking for (1) more cheese, and (2) *female* rats.

Comment: @RonJohn - The question was not whether the researcher was alive at the end, only whether the mouse was trying to kill him then.

Comment: @Adamant read the story.  It's very short.

Comment: The last quote makes more sense if (minor spoiler) it includes a previous couple of sentences, which establish that Barney isn't a *mouse*, but a *rat*.

Comment: Agree with @RonJohn: The story is very short, and you will have zero doubts about what happened by the end.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that last message seemed completely legit. Don't know why you are suspicious of Barney.

Comment: Seems like a weird prequel to "Flowers for Algernon".